# C to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips

I was trying to solve this and convert it to MIPS assembly code 
but the answer in the book confused me.so, can anyone explain how this code get this result in c ?

> B[g] = A[f] + A[f+1];

I have inserted comments for what I think that's right please correct me if I was wrong.

> Assume we have variables f, g, h, i, j stored in $s0, $s1, $s2, $s3 and $s4, respectively. Assume the base addresses of arrays A and B are at $s6 and $s7.

The code:

```
add $t0, $s6, $s0  #This will add f bytes to the base address and it's not equal to A[f].
add $t1, $s7, $s1  #This will add g bytes to the base address and it's not equal to B[g]
lw $s0, 0($t0)     #This will point to the value in (f +base address of A +0) bytes
lw $t0, 4($t0)     #This will point to the value in (f +base address of A +4) bytes
add $t0, $t0, $s0  
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

Comment: Is there a typo in the comments of the assembler snippet where "it's not equal" should read "it's now equal"?

Comment: This is no "explain my code" site.

Comment: @Olaf it's not my code it's the solution manual code and I think something wrong in this as they didn't multiply f and g with 4 to get the offset 
please read the question again.

Comment: You should have asked exactly that! As asked now, the question is clearly off-topic. Use the edit-link!

Comment: @BathantHegazy I think the code as is, implicitly assumes that both `f` and `g` are equal to 0.

Comment: @NlightNFotis 
It makes sense now. 
thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiled fragment annotated by me:

```
add $t0, $s6, $s0
```

add and store in register `t0` whatever is in register `s6` and `s0`. Since you have pointed out that `f` is stored in `s0` and the base address of `A` is stored in `s6`, this adds the addresses in preparation for a register indirect load later on. More simply `A[f] == *(A + f)` in C, and this is preparing for the `(A + f)` de-reference later on.

```
add $t1, $s7, $s1
```

The same thing happening for `B` and `g`. Add their contents and store them in an intermediate register, to be later used as address based de-reference targets.

```
lw $s0, 0($t0)
```

This is loading to the `s0` register, using what's known as the `register-indirect` addressing mode of the cpu, whatever is at the address pointed to by `t0` plus 0 bytes. In c this is equal to `s0 = *(A + f)`.

```
lw $t0, 4($t0)
```

The same thing as above, only that this time it loads to register `t0` whatever is pointed at `t0` plus 4 bytes. Equal to C `t0 = *(A + f + 1)`.

```
add $t0, $t0, $s0
```

This is the point where it performs the addition in your code. It's equal to the C code fragment of `A[f] + A[f + 1]`.

```
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

This is storing the result of the previous addition to the address pointed to by `t1`.

~~~~~~~~~~~

If you are looking for some references for the code you have, I found both this [MIPS instruction set reference useful](http://alumni.cs.ucr.edu/~vladimir/cs161/mips.html) and, of course, [Matt Godbolt's interactive compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org).

If you want to see what code does what using the interactive compiler, just wrap your code in a `void` function, select as the compiler `x86 clang` and at the compiler options `--target=mips`. Then from the filter apply colourise, and you will be able to see what C code generates what assembly code, to get something like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
add $t0, $s6, $s0  # t0 = A + f
add $t1, $s7, $s1  # t1 = B + g
lw $s0, 0($t0)     # s0 = *(t0 + 0) = *(A + f) = A[f]
lw $t0, 4($t0)     # t0 = *(t0 + 4) = *(A + f + 1) = A[f+1]
add $t0, $t0, $s0  # t0 = t0 + s0 = A[f] + A[f+1]
sw $t0, 0($t1)     # *(t1 + 0) = *(B + g) = B[g] = t0
```

Remember that C pointer arithmetic scales by item size, but assembly uses bytes. Hence, advancing 4 bytes is advancing 1 item in C.

On second thought, this in fact means `f` and `g` should also be scaled by 4, which they don't seem to be.

Comment: This means that this solution is wrong as they must be scaled by 4 to get the offset  ? 
and thanks for trying to help :) .

Comment: and this lw $s0, 0($t0) will not equal A[f] ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2     # $t0 = f * 4
add $t0, $s6, $t0
sll $t1, $s1, 2     # $t1 = g * 4
add $t1, $s7, $t1
lw $s0, 0($t0)
lw $t0, 4($t0)
add $t0, $t0, $s0  
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

Yes, the code is missing these two lines, you just need to scale both `f` and `g` by 4.